# Is this some kind of H2 DB specific syntax?

Tags: sql, h2

I am new to H2 and only familiar with T-SQL. I see the following SQL syntax in a script to run on H2 DB.

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS ROOT SALT 'xxxxxxxxxxx' HASH 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ADMIN;
```

I found it on the [H2 SQL command page](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_user). Is this `SALT` and `HASH` syntax specific to H2? What version of SQL language does H2 stick to?

Comment: Every relational DBMS uses "SQL". But at the same time **every** DBMS has extensions to the language (SQL Server is no different - in fact it deviates from standard SQL for even basic things like the concatenation operator). And **no** DBMS fully complies with the SQL standard.

Comment: The comment from @a_horse_with_no_name sums it up. H2 does not stick to a specific version of the ANSI SQL standard, it just tries to be compatible with as many other databases as possible (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle,...). And it has extensions, to support important features (in this case: not use the plain text password in scripts; it can't because the plain text password is not available at all). If there is a standard for that, then I would be happy to use it.